# If possible to Insert Temp Table. Via Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#A') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #A

CREATE TABLE #A (AccountID BIGINT,MemberID VARCHAR(12),FirstName VARCHAR(50),LastName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #A VALUES('32323','Test3','Last4','999122'),('192506','999158','Vmtestone','Diamond')
SELECT * FROM #A
```

Is it possible to use a dynamic query to insert into another temp table using

```
SELECT * INTO Statement
```

I tried this code:

```
DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @B=('SELECT * INTO #B FROM #A')
EXEC (@B)

SELECT * FROM #B
```

But I have Error like this

> Invalid object name '#B'.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/temporary-table-with-dynamic-sql

Comment: For this to work, move you `SELECT * FROM #B` into the dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

`#B` only exists in the scope of the dynamic query, so you cannot select from it outside.

Change your code to be:

```
DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @B=('SELECT * INTO #B FROM #A; SELECT * FROM #B')
EXEC (@B)
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use global temp tables. just replace # to ##

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##A') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##A

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##B') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##B

CREATE TABLE ##A (AccountID BIGINT,MemberID VARCHAR(12),FirstName VARCHAR(50),LastName 
VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO ##A VALUES('32323','Test3','Last4','999122'), 
('192506','999158','Vmtestone','Diamond')
SELECT * FROM ##A

DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @B=('SELECT * into ##B FROM ##A')
print(@B)
EXEC(@B)

SELECT * FROM ##B
```

Answer (score 0):

As single `#` creates a local temporary tables, it won't be available inside `EXECUTE` statement. You can use global temporary table to access it outside scope of

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#A') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #A

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##B') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##B

CREATE TABLE #A (AccountID BIGINT,MemberID VARCHAR(12),FirstName VARCHAR(50),LastName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #A VALUES('32323','Test3','Last4','999122'),('192506','999158','Vmtestone','Diamond')
SELECT * FROM #A

DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @B = 'SELECT * INTO ##B FROM #A'
EXEC (@B)

SELECT * FROM ##B
```

Check the [**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db14f2f24719195a9c4dd85df14897ed).

Comment: Thanks you So Much

Comment: @kalirajan, great.. you can accept the answer if found useful.